# How to show default Playback Controls with the AS3 YouTube API?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube-api, controls, playback

I've read the YouTube API documentation to add the playback controls, but I'm not sure exactly where I'm supposed to specify these parameters.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=AS3#controls

I've tried to append "`&controls=1`" to the Player's URL when I load it inside of a **Loader** object, but they still don't show up.

Are they supposed to be called from somewhere else? Or set on the **player:Object**? for example:

```
player.controls = 1;
```

No matter my efforts, none of my attempts worked.

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is the URL parameters on the embed, as you suspected. To disable controls you can use this object embed, which will use AS3:

```
<object width="853" height="480"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&amp;controls=0">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&amp;controls=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="853" height="480" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
```

The parameters are passed in the embed src tag. Note that the source parameters needs to be URL encoded, so the parameter separator is "&amp;"

The alternative way is to use iframe embed

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?controls=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

A nice page to play around with is Youtube's demo page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo There you can get the full embed code for the parameters you've selected as well, but the object embed don't seem to generated there.

For embedding using javascript there is also the SWFObject library where you pass these parameters as flashVars:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=de#Embedding

Hope that helps,
Christian

Comment: You've demonstrated using an <iframe>, but this doesn't seem to work with pure AS3 embedding.

Comment: True, I've added an example using <object> embed as well that will embed in AS3.

Comment: Haha, well actually what I meant was I'm using the YouTube API in pure AS3, no HTML. The URL is called similarly as your <embed src="..." /> but it's all done with methods of the Loader class. That's what I'm after. Tried appending &controls=1 to the URL (as zero would hide the controls, I want to show them), still doesn't work in AS3.

Comment: oh, so advanced =) And I guess you tried if it worked with &amp;amp;controls=1 as well? It could be some crossdomain mess with having the youtube watch swf downloaded hosted on youtube.com and embed that in your swf that is hosted on another domain.

Comment: Hmm yeah I suppose. Maybe the playback controls SWF is distributed from a different URL / Domain that I have to grant access with the 'Security.allowDomain()' method. Might be easier just to create the controls myself / use the ones provided by the Flash CS6 UI components panel.